# create loop in batch for multiple export with ImageMagick

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, dos

Im trying to make a batch file that process multiple image files.

The files are named P_1316_0001.png P_1316_0002.png P_1316_0003.png etc..
LETs sqy P_1316 is VARSESSION)
thanks to the ImageMagick program i can convert an image directly with batch.

Basically what i want to do is :

Create a variable that would increment until there is no more file to convert in the folder. Comvert the file from png to jpg (convert %VARSESSION%*%i%.png %VARSESSION%*%i%.jpg) assuming that i is 0001

Well i hope you can help me.
i thank you

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

You're being a little restrictive with your question, but to suit the precise parameters you've specified,

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /l %%i in (10001,1,19999) do (
 set numb=%%i
 ECHO if exist %varsession%_!numb:~1!.png convert %varsession%_!numb:~1!.png %varsession%_!numb:~1!.jpg
)
ENDLOCAL
```

But there are much better ways, such as

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d %varsession%_*.png') do (
ECHO convert %%i %%~ni.jpg
)
```

Assuming that all files matching %varsession%_*.png are to be processed.

Note: keyword ECHO inserted to SHOW what the batch proposes to do. Remove the `ECHO` to actually perform the action

Comment: can you explain me what is ~ni ?

Comment: Sure - see `for /?` from the prompt. `%%~ni` means the NAME of the file `%%i` You can also use `f` for full-filename, `d` for drivename, `p` for pathname and `x` for extension - or any sensible combination of these, such as `%%~nxi`. Yo can also use `a` for attributes, `t` for date, `z` for size. OR you can use `%%~i` to remove `"quotes"` if the string in %%i  may be quoted. Further, you can use `%~n` where n is [0..9] to remove quotes from [or apply the other operators to] argument %n to the batch or procedure.