# Imagemagick - Batch script (Windows) for a folder

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have about 100 .jpg-files in a folder and I want to have the .jpg without the black border.

So I wrote this code and used it sucesfully for one .jpg-file in the prompt:

```
convert input.jpg -fuzz 50% -trim output.jpg
```

I use Imagemagick Version 7.0.7-Q16 for Windows.

[input.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkdIf.jpg)

[output.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhNee.jpg)

Because there are so many .jpegs in this folder, so I want to use a batch. My first step was to put the code above for one .jpeg in a batch.
But when I execute the batch, the result-jpg is the same like the input-jpg (with black border). Here my code from the batch-file:

```
magick convert input.jpg -fuzz 50% -trim output_batch.jpg
pause
```

In a second step I wanted to adapt ans expand the code to use it for all .jpgs in the folder. But as written above my first step to write a batch for one .jpg failed :-(

So any help or hint for my problem will be appreciated! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create loop in batch for multiple export with ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807586/create-loop-in-batch-for-multiple-export-with-imagemagick)

Answer (score 0):

In ImageMagick 7 magick replaces convert, but is added to all other tools such as identify, mogrify, etc.

The simplest way to process a whole folder of images in that way is to use mogrify. Create new directory to hold your output images. Change directory to your current directory. Then

```
magick mogrify -path path\to\new_folder -format jpg -fuzz 50% -trim +repage *
```

This will give the output images the same name as the input images, but place them in a new folder to avoid overwriting your input.

No scripting is needed in this case.

Comment: That's it! Thank you for your answer!